# Content History Component Not Found

Tags: joomla-3.x, component, articles

I have a Joomla installation which is on 3.6.5 and working on upgrading to 3.7. While carrying out a test upgrade on a dev version of the site, I got presented with an error about the contenthistory component not being found, when editing an article. Here it is:

[image: Joomla 3.7 message about missing component]

So I went back to my 3.6.5 installation, which doesn't display any error on articles, and clicked on the "Versions" button, to find an error there too "Component not found". Here it is:

[image]

So I don't know how long this has been broken for, since I don't make use of old versions very often, but need to get this fixed. Can anyone suggest what might have gone wrong? What to look for? And how to fix it?

Thanks.

Comment: try re-installing joomla core

Comment: Thanks. I did that just now but still get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like something's gone awry in your database at some point. Since the error is present in 3.6.5 then I'd assume its not related to 3.7.

Some possible things to try if you haven't already:

- Go to Extensions -> Manage -> Database and try running "fix" (Backup your database before running!)
- Go to Global Config and turn on Debug System & turn on Error Reporting to "Development" - any errors?
- Anything relevant in the error logs?

Please post any error messages you find that might help narrow down the issue.

Are you only seeing this error in articles? What about under the Component menu?

Comment: Thanks for this. I ran fix on the database which didn't help. I turned on "debug system" and set "error reporting" to "development" as you said. Nothing of interest showing up when editing an article that I can see, just some duplicate database queries. Nothing in the error logs. What do you mean about errors under the Component menu? Nothing I can see. Where should I look?